# How to combine color field and colored markers on one map?

Tags: python, matplotlib, maps, cartopy

**Goal**: to plot the regression coefficient as a color field and markers of certain values (in my case it is EOF analysis, so eigenvector values) in each location.

**Problems**:

1. when I add line s = df['EOF1'] to the scatter plot markers do not appear at all
   How can I make markers differ in color and possibly size and stick to geographical coordinates?
2. In which order should I have my code for markers to not be under the land filling? I tried but nothing worked.
3. This weird line at the bottom that appears when I add markers
4. Maybe there is a more efficient way altogether. I'd like to be able to hover so was looking into holoviews and plotly for a solution, but couldn't make it work.
   Thank you!

```
import matplotlib                 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
import cartopy                  
import cartopy.crs as ccrs 
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (18, 6), subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})
ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', '50m', edgecolor='face', facecolor='#d3d3d3'))

PC2.plot(cmap='plasma')
ax.scatter(
    x=tg_meta["longitude"],
    y=tg_meta["latitude"],
    s = eof_tg['EOF1'],
    marker='s'
)
```

[image]

Comment: in general you can use `zorder` to stack artists in matplotlib plots... also maybe you're interested in giving [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) a try? (it's a wrapper around cartopy I'm developing that simplifies adding annotations & markers quite a bit... https://eomaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#annotations)

Comment: Wow! Thanks, Raphael, I will give it a try!